# Testing vertical scrollbar exists in jquery fails

Tags: jquery, scrollbar

I have written the following code and it returns undefined

```html
if(('#listSearchOptions').scrollHeight !== ('#listSearchOptions').clientHeight){
                    $('#listSearchOptions').css({"height":"auto", "max-height":""}); 
                    console.log("Height..." + ('#listSearchOptions').clientHeight); //results undefined
                }
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed `$` and you use regular javascript expression: replace `.scrollHeight` by `[0].scrollHeight`. And replace `.clientHeight` by `.height()`

This work fine

```
if($('#listSearchOptions')[0].scrollHeight !== $('#listSearchOptions').height()){
    $('#listSearchOptions').css({"height":"auto", "max-height":""}); 
    console.log("Height..." + $('#listSearchOptions').height()); //results undefined
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I am getting -  console.log("Height..." + $('#listSearchOptions')[0].clientHeight); height 0 for all these. Wonndering why?!

Comment: Why you used clientHeight? Please use .height() without [0]. See my answer

Comment: Thanks, that was by miss.